# Whether there exists a probabilistic automaton satisfying $\Pr \{ x \in L\}=\frac{\Pr \{ x \in L_1\}}{\Pr \{ x \in L_1\}+\Pr \{ x \in L_2\}}$

Tags: automata, probability-theory

Suppose that there are two probabilistic automata $A_1$ and $A_2$ with a same finite alphabet $\Sigma$. The languages of them are $\mathcal{L}_{1} \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and $\mathcal{L}_{2} \subseteq \Sigma^*$ respectively.

For every input $x \in \Sigma^*$, $\Pr \{ x \in \mathcal{L}_{1}\}=p_1(x)$ and $\Pr \{ x \in \mathcal{L}_{2}\}=p_2(x)$. Whether there exists a probabilistic automaton $A$ satisfying $$\Pr \{ x \in \mathcal{L}\}=\frac{p_1(x)}{p_1(x)+p_2(x)}$$ where $\mathcal{L} \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is the language of $A$?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried constructing such an automaton $A$? Have you tried finding $A_1,A_2$ such that no such $A$ exists?

Comment: What about the trivial answer $\mathcal{L}_1 = \{\}$?